# Tensorflow EfficientNetB0 Error: TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.math.truediv" (type TFOpLambda)

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, dtype, efficientnet

Encountered the following error when creating a Feature Extraction EfficientNetB0 model from `tensorflow.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a777a6ba699b> in <module>
----> 1 model_00 = create_feature_extraction_model()
      2 model_00.summary()

<ipython-input-22-b1a80357611c> in create_feature_extraction_model()
      1 def create_feature_extraction_model():
----> 2     base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
      3 
      4     base_model.trainable = False
      5 

~/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/applications/efficientnet.py in EfficientNetB0(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation, **kwargs)
    546                    classifier_activation='softmax',
    547                    **kwargs):
--> 548   return EfficientNet(
    549       1.0,
    550       1.0,

~/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/applications/efficientnet.py in EfficientNet(width_coefficient, depth_coefficient, default_size, dropout_rate, drop_connect_rate, depth_divisor, activation, blocks_args, model_name, include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation)
    332     # original implementation.
    333     # See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49930 for more details
--> 334     x = x / tf.math.sqrt(IMAGENET_STDDEV_RGB)
    335 
    336   x = layers.ZeroPadding2D(

~/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/core/tf_op_layer.py in handle(self, op, args, kwargs)
    105         isinstance(x, keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
    106         for x in tf.nest.flatten([args, kwargs])):
--> 107       return TFOpLambda(op)(*args, **kwargs)
    108     else:
    109       return self.NOT_SUPPORTED

~/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.math.truediv" (type TFOpLambda).

`x` and `y` must have the same dtype, got tf.float16 != tf.float32.

Call arguments received by layer "tf.math.truediv" (type TFOpLambda):
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float16)
  • y=tf.Tensor(shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
  • name=None
```

The images are from tensorflow_datasets `food101`. The Image Shapes are (224, 224, 3) with `dtype=tf.float32`. And The model is trying to take advantage of Mixed Precision with `'mixed_float16'`.

```
def create_feature_extraction_model():
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)

    base_model.trainable = False

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE, name='input_layer')
    x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_classes)(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(dtype=tf.float32, name='output_layer')(x)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs, name='food101_model')

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

The model is to be trained on a Laptop (offline) with the following GPU specs.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   56C    P0    13W /  N/A |      7MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      6850      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

When trying to create model. The above Error occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same error with TF 2.9.2, however **not** going for the mixed_precision policy "fixed" it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this error as well and apparently, changing the tensorflow version back to 2.4.1 version solved it. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of the-under-the-hood explanation for this error.

Comment: You should probably add information on how to downgrade the tensorflow version as well. A link to an article may be sufficient, but it would be great if you have some pointer on how to salvage the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I found out for this dataset, we just need to use the float32 dtype.

policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.Policy('float32')
tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy)

Hope this helps the next person.

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/mixed_precision/Policy